# template argument deduction for destructor

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, standards, destructor

Should a compiler deduce the template argument when the destructor of a class is called ?
The following piece of code :

```
#include <iostream> 
template <typename T>
class A{
};
int main(){
   A<int> * a = new A<int>();
   a->~A();
}
```

compiles fine on gcc (g++ 4.3.4) but fails on XLC++ with

```
line 30.5: 1540-0210 (S) "A" is not a base class of
"A<int>"
```

Which of the two behavior is expect from a standard compliant compiler ?

Comment: First, short of placement-new reasons I'm stretched to think of a reason to do this (though that would be a perfectly valid reason). Second, interesting naming, as one is not derived from anything, and the other is consequently not a base therein. Third, did you try `b->derived<int>::~derived()` on both platforms? Finally, for what its worth, Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang) supports *both* the format you specified and the one I did. I believe the standard would support the latter without exception, but I would have to dust off my copy to quote where and why. EDIT: `p->~derived<int>()` also works.

Comment: I asked the question because i am was interested in what was the standard compliant behavior.Your suggestion work, but doesnt answer that question...

Comment: That would be why it was a comment, and not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The C++03 standard (I doubt that the C++11 standard will be any different) has the following paragraph (C++03 14.3/5 [temp.arg]):

> An explicit destructor call (12.4) for an object that has a type that is a class template specialization may explicitly specify the *template-arguments*. [*Example:*
>
> ```
>     template<class T> struct A {
>         ~A();
>     };
>     void f(A<int>* p, A<int>* q) {
>         p->A<int>::~A();       // OK: destructor call
>         q->A<int>::~A<int>();  // OK: destructor call
>     };
> ```
>
> *--end example*]

Clause 12.4/12 [class.dtor] describes the explicit destructor call in terms of a call to a regular member function and has an example showing the explicit destructor call with both qualified and unqualified versions for the destructor's type.

To me, this clearly indicates that the intent of the standard is that each of

```
A<int> * a = new A<int>();
a->~A();
a->~A<int>();
a->A<int>::~A();
a->A<int>::~A<int>();
```

should be valid.
The fact that the first two are not mentioned in the example in 14.4/12 should not affect this, as examples are not normative.